# Working with arraylist in java/android

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I am little confused as to what -1 represents in the following arraylist. Can someone help me out please, thanks.

```
toyList.add(new toyStore(toyName[0], toyIcon.getResourceId(0, -1)));
toyList.add(new toyStore(toyName[1], toyIcon.getResourceId(1, -1)));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the following link http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/TypedArray.html#getResourceId(int, int)

"Value to return if the attribute is not defined or not a resource."

So basically it is a default value if what you are looking for  isn't found.

Answer (score 0):

```
getResourceId (int index, int defValue)
```

It's the defValue is stands for the Value to return if the attribute is not defined or not a resource.

more explanation :

> public int getResourceId (int index, int defValue)
>
> Added in API level 1 Retrieve the resource identifier for the
>   attribute at index. Note that attribute resource as resolved when the
>   overall TypedArray object is retrieved. As a result, this function
>   will return the resource identifier of the final resource value that
>   was found, not necessarily the original resource that was specified by
>   the attribute.
>
> Parameters index  Index of attribute to retrieve. defValue    Value to
>   return if the attribute is not defined or not a resource. Returns
>   Attribute resource identifier, or defValue if not defined.

Answer (score 0):

`getResourceId(0, -1)` gives the resource Id at index 0 of `toyIcon` or it will return -1 if the attribute is not defined or not a resource.
In the docs

```
public int getResourceId (int index, int defValue)
Parameters
index   Index of attribute to retrieve.
defValue    Value to return if the attribute is not defined or not a resource.
Returns
Attribute resource identifier, or defValue if not defined.
```

See this: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/TypedArray.html#getResourceId(int, int)

Similarly `toyIcon.getResourceId(1, -1)` will return the resource Id at index 1 of `toyIcon` or -1 if the attribute is not defined or not a resource.